# What are the most beloved acts of worship?

Tags: ibadah, deeds

I have became a Muslim at age of 15 and now I was thinking how can I make God Almighty to be very happy with me and to be also one of special people。  Can you tell me what are the most beloved acts of worship? I mean to make a list which is the most beloved and also in deeds

Comment: List questions are rather off-topic here! However in some SE sites they would be accepted to some extent if OP -as you did- is excepting a list or lists!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in hadith qudsi , Allah says :

> "My slave approaches Me with nothing more beloved to Me than what I have made obligatory upon him, and My slave keeps drawing nearer to Me with voluntary works until I love him.  "  [[Al-Bukhari]](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/81/91)

So doing obligatory works (doing wajib and not doing haram) is the best. Adding voluntary works (doing Mustahab and not doing Makruh) to that , is even better .

check here for list of works : http://www.newmuslimguide.com/